# SwiftUI how to pass data to previous screen on dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-form

I want pass data on dismissing of `presentViewController` to previous screen. Here I would like to use block to pass data to previous screen as UIKitApp. But I'm not getting idea to pass data. What are the `options` we have to pass data to back?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModel = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                showModel.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Show filters")
            }).sheet(isPresented: $showModel, content: {
                FilterView()
            })
        }
    }
}

struct FilterView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var onDismiss: ((_ model: Filter) -> Void)?

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                // Pass data from here to ContentView
                let filter = Filter(fromDate: "10/07/2021", toDate: "12/07/2021")
                onDismiss?(filter)
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("Applay Filters")
            }).padding()
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct Filter {
    var fromDate: String
    var toDate: String
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `@Binding` for that (or `@StateObject`, `@ObservedObject`, `@Environmentobject` with `@ObservableObject` using MVVM Design Pattern)

The code below is an example using @Binding.

**Added/Edited Lines**

```
Text("\(filter.fromDate) and \(filter.toDate)") // to see the changed values

@State var filter = Filter(fromDate: "", toDate: "") // in ContentView

@Binding var filter: Filter // in FilterView

FilterView(filter: $filter) // $ used for @Binding parameter
```

**Full Code**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showModel = false
    @State var filter = Filter(fromDate: "", toDate: "")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(filter.fromDate) and \(filter.toDate)")
            Button(action: {
                showModel.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Show filters")
            }).sheet(isPresented: $showModel, content: {
                FilterView(filter: $filter)
            })
        }
    }
}

struct FilterView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var onDismiss: ((_ model: Filter) -> Void)?
    @Binding var filter: Filter

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                // Pass data from here to ContentView
                filter = Filter(fromDate: "10/07/2021", toDate: "12/07/2021")
                onDismiss?(filter)
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("Applay Filters")
            }).padding()
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct Filter {
    var fromDate: String
    var toDate: String
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks @Taeeun onDismiss we can the date```swift .sheet(isPresented: $showModel, onDismiss: {
                print("\(filter.fromDate) and \(filter.toDate)")
            }, content: {
                FilterView(filter: $filter)
            })'''

Comment: Any other ways? We have to create object right?  `@State var filter: Filter(fromDate: "", toDate: "") `

Comment: @iOSDeveloper you are welcome! Can I ask you again, what do you mean?

If you want to create object without initial values like `@State var filter: Filter()`, then you can use Optional(use `?` at the end of type) like `var fromDate: String?` and `var toDate: String?`.
Then you can use `@State var filter: Filter()`
And you have to change this `filter.fromDate` to `filter.fromDate ?? "no date"`, because it's now Optional value. (or `filter.fromDate!`)

Comment: What is the use of ```onDismiss``` closure?

Comment: @Vinod none. that's his logic. the filter variable getting assigned a value is enough

Comment: Hi, I didn't get the onDismiss closure? Would you kindly provide more details? @TaeeunKim